# C# SerialPort communication protocol

Tags: c#, arduino, port

I did write a small C# app that reads from a COM port a series of numbers sent by an Arduino board.

Question:

If the Arduino sends a single value every 500ms but my C# program reads a single value every 1s doesn't the C# get left behind the Arduino? If that is true, does the data sent from Arduino get stored in a buffer or is it simply discarded?

[Edit]

Bellow is the code I use to read from COM

---

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.Timer tCOM;
...

tCOM.Interval = 1000;
tCOM.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
...

SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = defaultPortName;
port.BaudRate = 9600; 
port.Open();
.....

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log("Time to read from COM");

    //read a string from serial port
    string l;
    if ((l = port.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
    ......

    }

}
```

Comment: Alex, How do you read from serial. Post your code.

Comment: @FeliceM updated with my code

Answer (score 4):

Serial port communications normally require *flow control*.  A way for the transmitter to know that the receiver is ready to receive data.  This is often overlooked, especially in Arduino projects.  Which tends to work out okay, serial ports are very slow and modern machines are very fast compared to the kind of machines that first started using serial ports.

But clearly, in your scenario something is going to go bang! after a while.  Your Arduino will cause a buffer overflow condition when the receive buffer in the PC fills up to capacity.  And that causes irretrievable loss of data.  Listening for a notification of this condition is something else that's often skipped, you must register an event handler for the SerialPort.ErrorReceived event.  You'd expect a SerialError.Overrun notification in this case.  There's no clean way to recover from this condition, a full protocol reset is required.

There are two basic ways to implement flow control on serial ports to avoid this error.  The most common one is to use hardware handshaking, using the RTS (Request To Send) and CTS (Clear To Send) signals.  Provided by Handshake.RequestToSend.  The PC will automatically turn the RTS signal off when its receive buffer gets too full.  Your Arduino must pay attention to the CTS signal and not send anything when it is off.

The second way is software handshaking, the receiver sends a special byte to indicate whether it is ready to receive data.  Provided by Handshake.XonXoff, which uses the standard control characters Xon (Ctrl+Q) and Xoff (Ctrl+S).  Suitable only when the communication protocol doesn't otherwise use these control codes in their data.  In other words, when you transmit text instead of binary data.

The third way is a completely different approach, very common as well, you make the device only ever send anything when the PC asks for it.  A master-slave protocol.  Having enough room in the receive buffer for the response is easy to guarantee.  You specify specific *commands* in your protocol, commands that the PC sends to query for a specific data item.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a serial port for input, a buffer (queue) is automatically created to hold incoming data until it is read by your program. This buffer is typically 4096 bytes in size (although that may vary according to the version of Windows, serial port driver etc.).

A 4096-byte buffer is normally sufficient in almost all situations. At the highest standard baud rate (115200 baud) it corresponds to more than 300 msecond of storage (FIFO) first in first out, so as long as your program services the serial port at least three times a second no data should be lost. In your particular case, because you read the serial every 1 second, you may loose data if the timing and the buffered data do not match.

However in exceptional circumstances it may be useful to be able to increase the size of the serial input buffer. Windows provides the means to request an increased buffer size, but there is no guarantee that the request will be granted.

Personally I prefer to have a continuous stream of data from Arduino and decide in my c# app what to do with those data but at least I am sure I do not loose information due to limitation of the hardware involved.

Update:
Playing with Arduino quite often, I also agree with the third option given by Hans in his answer. Basically your app should send to Arduino a command to get printed out (Serial.Print or Serial.Println) the data you need and be ready to read it.